# bokeh with IPython Notebook widget: extra figures apppearing

Tags: python, ipython, bokeh

Clicking the 'up' button in the following code produces a sequence of figures rather than updating the existing figure. How does one update an existing figure?

```
from IPython.html import widgets
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from IPython.display import display
from numpy.random import randn
bp.output_notebook()

m = 1000
n = 1000
df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(m, n)).cumsum()

bp.hold()
bp.figure(figsize=(4, 8))


def doplot(i):
    bp.line(df.index, df.icol(i), color='red', legend='here')
    bp.show()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.doplot()
    def incr(self, something):
        self.i += 1
        print(self.i)
        self.doplot()
    def decr(self, something):
        self.i -= 1
        self.doplot()
    def doplot(self):
        doplot(self.i)
a = A()
button = widgets.ButtonWidget(description='up')
button.on_click(a.incr)
buttond = widgets.ButtonWidget(description='down')
buttond.on_click(a.decr)

display(button)
display(buttond)
```

Comment: Do you want one plot with one line, that updates the single line when the buttons are pushed? Or do you want want plot, with potentially many lines, that adds new lines when the buttons are pushed?

Comment: Both I suppose. Let's pick the first. The main thing is that I want one plot not many.

Comment: The canonical way to do this involves the bokeh server. You keep ahold of the data source for the plot, and then update it and push to the server, and the plot updates automatically. Here is an example:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/notebook/animated.ipynb

That said, I think it would be possible to add a function that re-draws a plot in the IPython notebook in place, but I don't believe this is currently possible in any simple way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work with the `ipywidgets` function [`interact`](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/d03bc587afaedb20a25e7238c6303b50a4e0fc54/examples/Using%20Interact.ipynb)

This way everytime you interact with a `widget` the bokeh plot will be reloaded instead of a new one being appended to the existing one.

Here a minimal example, with minor updates to make it work with the new versions:

```
import ipywidgets
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from IPython.display import display
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas
bp.output_notebook()

m = 1000
n = 1000

df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(m, n)).cumsum()

def create_plot(swapp_axis):
    fig = bp.figure()
    if swapp_axis:
        fig.scatter(df.icol(0), df.index)
    else:
        fig.scatter(df.index, df.icol(0))
    bp.show(fig)

swapp_axis = ipywidgets.Checkbox(
    description='swapp_axis',     
    value=False)                                    

ipywidgets.interact( create_plot, swapp_axis=swapp_axis)
```

p.s.
I see this an old answer. If you found another solution in the meantime, please let me know.